# pingasync.SendAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloud

Calling `pingasync.SendAsync(mac, "ping");` am getting error this when i ping it async way give some solution in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter is userToken: an object passed to the method invoked when the ping completes. You can set it to null instead of "ping"